# How to deploy Gophish in a running IIS Server

Tags: iis, rewrite

I am a beginner in Windows Server management. Currently, i have a VPS which already has a website running in IIS 10. Also have a domain which already point out to the Server's IP Address for that running website.

I use Gophish for windows which come in .exe file. I set the config.json to use port 3333 for admin_server and port 8080 for the phish_server, and Gophish run successfully in the VPS.

Now, i need the landing page of my Gophish campaign in the server to be accessed by the target, but i don't know how to set it up in the IIS Manager.

i've tried adding a site in IIS, but putting the path of Gophish folder in the physical path didn't work. i think it is due to the Gophish is an executable file, not .html and such.

i've also tried adding a new binding in Default Web Site to port 8080, but then the site cannot be run due to the error saying that the file being used in another process. i believe it is due to the port already used in the running Gophish server.

another thing that i tried was add a new binding in Default Web Site to port 8081, and create URL Rewrite to 8080, but it results in HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

any help would be appreciated

PS: i have checked similar requests on gophish's github page, and they don't really offer support for IIS configuration

Comment: Probably a good idea to follow the system requirements for this product. Looks straightforward for the platforms that they support, Linux. They don't even have its own service manager, they only punt and say use nssm.  https://docs.getgophish.com/user-guide/installation